# if 6 bullets, of which 3 are blanks, are randomly inserted into a gun, what is the probability that the first 3 bullets fired will be blank

Tags: probability

I'm a newbie in learning probability, need your help in solving this.
Given that 6 bullets, of which 3 are  blank, are randomly inserted into a gun, what is the probability that the first $3$ bullet fired will be blank?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  So you are aware, this isn't a homework site...people here don't like to answer questions which show no effort at all.  Can you indicate what you have tried?  For example...what is the probability that the first one is a blank?  Given that the first is a blank, what is the probability that the second is also blank?

Comment: Note;  I'm assuming that this gun fires from cartridge to cartridge, the way a revolver rotates.  Thus, you never fire the same "slot" twice.  The problem (and the answer) is different if, say, you spin the cylinder after each shot.

Comment: can you see what the probability of the first fired being a blank?

Answer (score 0):

There are ${6\choose3}=20$ ways to put $6$ bullets, $3$ of them blank, into a gun. Exactly one of these has the three blank bullets in the slots $1$–$3$. The requested probability therefore is ${1\over20}$.